How To Modify This Query Function?
I am trying to show only the values in SUM(H) that are less than 37 but when I tried, its not working at all. I hope someone could help me fix what seems to be the problem with my query function. Here is the query function that I am using in google sheet.
=QUERY('Table (Weekly)'!$B$1:$V,
"SELECT B, F, SUM(H), K, L, M
WHERE B is not null AND SUM(H) < 37
GROUP BY B, F, K, L, M
")


Would you be able to provide your sample sheet, with your initial output, and also your expected output so that we can further help you. You may use this anonymous sheet maker to create your reproducible example without your email being exposed.

Use nested QUERY() to filter based on aggregated values. Try-
=QUERY(QUERY('Table (Weekly)'!$B$1:$V,
"SELECT B, F, SUM(H), K, L, M
WHERE B is not null GROUP BY B, F, K, L, M"),"WHERE Col3<37")


Hi,
This one worked. Thank you so much!
